# Update s2Member profile info

Tags: wordpress

I just started working with S2Memeber and am having problems finding a way to save/update extended user information.

I know to use 's2get' to get info, and there appears not to be something like 's2put'.

How do I go about updating/adding the additional user data that is retrieved with the s2get shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie. Someone upvoted this, so I hope this answer helps.

You don't actually do this through S2Member, which, of course, is good. Instead you use the native WP functionality.

```
$meta_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', true );    
    $meta_value['company_name'] = 'My Company';
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', $meta_value);
```